# @Constructorresult with self join class mapping

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Can some one explain me how to code annotation for a scenario where self join class is used.

In my scenario, I am using native query for which I need to pass some inputs.

For the SQL result mapping, I am using @constructorresult. But not sure how to configure self class join based on specific column

Answer (score 0):

### Example with ConstructorResult

Let's say we have a very complex entity `ComplexObject` with many relations to other objects.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "complex_object")
public class ComplexObject {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id_complex_object")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "label")
    private String label;

    // More relations...

}
```

I want a query to retrieve only the id and the label of this entity.

In `ComplexObject`, I define a new `NamedNativeQuery` as following.

```
@NamedNativeQueries({
        @NamedNativeQuery(name = "ComplexObject.getIdAndLabel", query = "SELECT co.id_complex_object, co.label FROM complex_object", resultSetMapping = "SimpleObject")
})
```

The important part of this `NamedNativeQuery` is the `resultSetMapping = "SimpleObject"`.

Then I can define a `SimpleObject` that is not a entity and match my query as following :

```
public class SimpleObject {

    private Integer id;
    private String label;

    /**
     * This constructor is very important !
     * Its signature has to match the SqlResultSetMapping defined in the entity class.
     * Otherwise, an exception will occur.
     */
    public SimpleObject(Integer id, String label) {
        this.id = id;
        this.label = label;
    }

    // Getters and setters...
}
```

Then I can define the `SqlResultSetMapping` in `ComplexObject` as following :

```
@SqlResultSetMappings({
    @SqlResultSetMapping(name = "SimpleObject", classes = {
        @ConstructorResult(targetClass = SimpleObject.class, columns = {
            @ColumnResult(name = "id_complex_object", type = Integer.class),
            @ColumnResult(name = "label", type = String.class)
        })
    })
})
```

It's done.

The `NamedNativeQuery` will use `SimpleObject` `SqlResultSetMapping` to construct a `SimpleObject` (throught the constructor) so your query returns a `SimpleObject` instead of `ComplexObject`.

Comment: Thanks for the example, but I am looking for a scenario where ComplexObject contains an attribute of type ComplexObject

Comment: It doesn't make any difference what kind of object you have as long as it has a representation in your database. If your `ComplexObject` contains a `ComplexObject`, you will only be able to retrieve its ID since you want to use `ConstructorResult` and `NamedNativeQuery`.